# Time constants and steady states of decaying quantities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is often said that an exponentially decaying quantity reaches its steady state
in five time constants, that is, at t = 5τ . Explain why this statement is not
literally true but is correct for all practical purposes.

I differentiated the decay model and substituted $t = 5\tau$:

$r(t) = r_0e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$

$\frac{dr}{dt} = -\frac{1}{\tau}r_0e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$

$= -\frac{1}{\tau}r_0e^{-\frac{5\tau}{\tau}}$

$= -\frac{1}{\tau}r_0e^{-5}$

I set $\frac{dr}{dt} = 0$ to find the steady state,

$\frac{dr}{dt} = -\frac{1}{\tau}r_0e^{-5} = 0$

So intuitively, $\frac{dr}{dt}$ tends to zero for large values of $\tau$. Is this sufficient to show that the statement is not literally true but correct for all practical purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that after five time constants, the error from the equilibrium state is multiplied by $\exp(-5)\approx 0.0067$, or divided by about $150$.  If you didn't start *too* far from equilibrium, you are pretty close now.